# get list from index of other list python

Tags: python-3.x, list

I have 2 lists:

```
a=[0,2,0,5]
b=[3,4,5,6]
```

I want to find remove all the 0 from list a and remove corresponding values(with same index) in list b.
My result should be:

```
a=[2,5]
b=[4,6]
```

until now I did:

```
a = [idx for idx, val in enumerate(a) if val == 0]
```

and get `a=[1,3]`
but I don't manage to get the corresponding list in b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a=[0,2,0,5]
b=[3,4,5,6]

a, b = map(list, zip(*[[i, j] for i, j in zip(a, b) if i != 0]))

print(a)
print(b)
```

Prints:

```
[2, 5]
[4, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

You got `a` list indexes correctly, to get valid elements from `b` list the easy way is to do

```
[b[idx] for idx, val in enumerate(a) if val != 0]
```

and to get `a` values

```
[val for val in a if val != 0]
```

---

to do it in one iteration:

```
x = [(val, b[idx]) for idx, val in enumerate(a) if val != 0]
```

or

```
x = [(val_a, val_b) for val_a, val_b in zip(a, b) if val_a != 0]
```

but it gives you list of tuples, but you can use some python magic to turn it into two lists

```
a, b = map(list, zip(*x))
```